Speed up the linear mixed model fitting in R lme4qtl packages
Fitting a linear mixed model (LMM) with kinship matrix as random effect is a quite time-consuming task, especially in R. I am trying to apply the function relmatLmer in package lme4qtl, which is a lme4 extension enabling the kinship matrix included in a LMM, on a dataset with about 500 samples and 30K "variants" (not the numeric variable but factorial). By fitting
Model1 = relmatLmer(PHE ~ PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4+PC5+(1|ID), data, 
                    relmat = list(ID = Kin),
                    REML=F,
                    control = lmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap",optCtrl=list(xtol_abs=1e-6, ftol_abs=1e-6),calc.derivs = F))

and turn into variants loop
Model2 = update(Model1, .~.+(1|G))

in which G is a single factorial variant. Then two models were compared by function anova to get the significance of a G. However, this takes about 20 hours, even i paralleled the loop by foreach in package doSNOW with 40 threads.
I have already applied some methods to improve the efficiency, such as the parameters set in the lmerControl in model1, and the paralleled model2 fitting, but the time used is still not ideal. Is there any way, or any other alternative packages/functions to speed up the regression?
Thanks.

What is the RAM situation? Could the OS already be swapping? Parallelization can be counter-productive then. You could try using an optimizes BLAS.

@Roland Thanks. The RAM capacity does not seems to be an issue, the RAM used for every thread is about 2-3GB, and i ran it on the PBS server with 256GB RAM per worker node. I've also run the task in parallel with 16 threads on my PC equipped with an i7-14700K, which offers robust single-core performance, and it took about 3 hours to finish. The 128GB of RAM on my PC was also sufficient throughout the process. I'm intrigued by your BLAS recommendation but not very familiar with it.  Is there any R packages could possibly wrapped optimized BLAS library into my working flow?

P.S. Although 3 hours seems to be acceptable, but i have more larger datasets than the current one, so I need a more efficiently workflow. @Roland

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ropenblas/index.html There are also tutorials out there for how to link a different BLAS to R. I have never needed it but my understanding is that it is quite simple.

It's hard to advise without having a sense of the nature of the data. What do the data ranges look like? Sometimes the problem is due to the data range (e.g., 0.0001 to 1500). Rescaling the data (e.g., multiplying them by 10,000) can speed things up.

A better BLAS is definitely worth trying.  I would be interested in some benchmarking to know how the time per run is divided into model setup vs optimization (this would be easier to separate with a basic lmer fit, where you could use the machinery in ?modular to split the problem up ...
